# How To disable xubuntu icons from terminal?

Tags: xubuntu

I'm using xubuntu as a TV Interface in a cafe, I would like to remove icons, auto-hide the panel and change the wallpaper from terminal. I was successful in auto-hiding the panel using "xfconf-query", I'm still working on wallpaper . I would like to know equivalent command for disabling icons too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the wallpaper

First put the image you want in the correct folder

```
sudo mv path/to/your/image /usr/share/backgrounds/xfce
```

If you just want a default one, you can find there names like this

```
ls /usr/share/backgrounds/xfce
```

Then to change the image

```
xfconf-query --channel xfce4-desktop --property /backdrop/screen0/monitor0/image-path --set /usr/share/backgrounds/xfce/your-image-here
```

To remove the desktop icons, you can use this code provided by @AJefferiss in the comments

```
xfconfig-query -c xfce4-desktop -np '/desktop-icons/style' -t 'int' -s '0'
```

You can change the parameter '0' to manipulate the icons

`'0'` Is no icons `'1'` Sets currently running apps as icons `'2'`    Will restore Home/File System/etc icons.

Comment: yes , instead I replaced my image with default one in /usr/share/xfce4/backdrop/xubuntu-wallpaper.png and it worked.
As i'm doing all this using reverse tunneling (ssh) with help of fabric , I have problem with setting "xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /desktop-icons/file-icons/show-home -s false" as it says property not defined , you need to create one.

Comment: To remove the desktop icons you can run the following `xfconfig-query -c xfce4-desktop -np '/desktop-icons/style' -t 'int' -s '0'`

0 - Disables all desktop icons
1 - Sets currently running apps as icons 
2 - Re-enables Home/File System/etc icons

Comment: @AJefferiss May I use this in the answer ? I could not find this code, of course I will credit you.

Comment: @markkirby of course, not wanting to create a answer with a single command in it is why I add it as a comment

Comment: @AJefferiss Thanks, I will check your profile and give you some upvotes as a thanks.

Comment: @Nagraj93 Please see the edit, also as you are a new user, if this helps you please `accept` the answer with the check mark on the left to say thanks.